# RxJava sample() is CPU intensive

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm trying to implement a download progress bar using RxJava (on Android). I want to be able to report (download) progress with a 0.1% resolution. However, if the connection is fast the file may be downloaded very fast and produce a lot of events.

Therefore I assumed I had to limit the amounts of events using .sample(). My implementation looks like this:

```
        mRxSubscription = downloadProgressChangeObservable
                .ofType(DownloadProgress.class)
                .sample(16, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) // This is problematic
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Action1<DownloadProgress>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(DownloadProgress downloadProgress) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "Recieved downloadProgress event. Progress: " + downloadProgress.getProgress());
                        setProgressPercent(downloadProgress);
                    }
                }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "error: " + throwable.toString());
                    }
                });
```

If I just have the subscription (without .sample() ) everything works great, except when the download manager is emitting events too fast. However, adding the .sample() my CPU load increases to ~30% at all times - also when no events are being emitted.

I am not sure I understand this. Neither call(DownloadProgress) or call(Throwable) is being called, but it feels like the subscription is constantly pulling for new events.

Comment: every 16 milis? it more then 60Hz ... more then render refresh time ... just give some reasonable value there (fx 500 - 1 per half second should be enough)

Comment: Don't know about how Android reacts to such frequent updates but if you don't even receive events at the end, there must be something wrong with the upstream. Since observeOn is battle tested and sample is dead simple, I'd see if downloadProgressChangeObservable somehow misbehaves. You can add doOnNext at various places to see where the values disappear. It is also possible that 16ms is so long that your upstream completes way before the sample even picks up any value.

Comment: @Selvin The entire reason for going for 60 fps was to get a smooth progress bar.

Comment: @akarnokd but I do get events. What puzzels me is that I get such a high CPU usage when I don't post any events (i.e. before I clock "download")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`sample`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/sample.html) docs,

> The Sample operator periodically looks at an Observable and emits
>   whichever item it has most recently emitted since the previous
>   sampling.

"Looks at" implies it is doing work each period, which accounts for your CPU usage. Every 16ms, it is firing off and looking to see if it needs to emit an item.  You should probably dial that back to 100-500ms depending on your UI constraints.

Comment: Thank you for this. Not the way I would expect it to work, but it explains the behavior I'm observing